# Get URL of active IE8 tab using VBscript

Tags: url, vbscript, internet-explorer-8

How can I tweak the vbscript code below to give me the URL of the ACTIVE tab in IE8? Instead of creating an object for Internet Explorer and navigating to a declared website, is it possible for me to use the AppActivate method to focus the window and get the URL?  Note: The vbscript would be used on the local machine of the user, and not embedded in another webpage.  Thanks!

```
Set IE=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
IE.Visible=false

IE.Navigate "http://www.google.com"

Do While IE.Busy
wScript.sleep 1000
Loop

WScript.Echo IE.Document.URL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get an *active* instance, you shouldn't use `CreateObject`. `GetObject` won't help you out here, either. You need to use the `Windows` collection of the `Shell.Application` object.

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each Window In Shell.Windows

    ' Make sure it's an Internet Explorer (iexplore) window...
    If InStr(1, Window.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        ' Display the URL of the current page...
        MsgBox Window.LocationUrl

    End If

Next
```